404 error after removing a security plugin
I recently removed a security plugin (Solid security). Now I get a 404 error every time I try to load a page other than the homepage. I’ve tried resetting the permalinks and checked that the .htaccess file is correct, but it still doesn’t work. The site works fine if I set the permalinks to the default structure. It’s as if it doesn’t read the permalink settings when loading the page, and I’m not sure where these settings are stored. Can anyone help me?

have you raised this with solid securitys support?

You'd better pay for the programmer's services. There could be many reasons for the problem.

Are you using any cache plugin? oR Go to settings->permalinks->refresh the page or use generic htaccess file, or try in another browser

Reactivate the plugin and start combing through it's settings to see if anything jumps out. After that, if it still happens when you deactivate, then start checking for any folders it installed (via FTP/SFTP) and check if it added any custom database tables.  Rebuild your .htaccess from scratch without anything extra added in and then rebuild your premalinks.
